# xltabular package - List of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, xltabular

This is my first question here.

When I use any package to make tables, my list of tables displays only their numbers.
However, I need to use xltabular to build the Table 2.4, but I get a different entry in the LoT. How can I remove the word "Table"?

[image: List of Tables]

---

Well, I think I am not able to provide an MWE since I am using a template from the university.

In this link, I have attached the .zip file with the template. The table can be found in the file 6-Revue_litterature.tex, the packages in Document.tex, and the definitions in MemoireThese.sty.

Thank you.

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1hoy.png)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?  It would go from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, but would only need one xltabular.  That would let us see how you're getting the result that you're getting.  (It should probably be at most 20 lines long.)

Answer (score 0):

Do not load package `caption`:

[image]

By the way:

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
\footnotesize
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.7cm}>{\centering}p{0.9cm}X@{}}
    \caption{Ternary.}\label{tab:ternary} \\
    \toprule
...
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup
```